# Driver Component Confusion with Windows Embedded

Tags: windows, embedded, drivers

I need some help from someone familiar with Windows Embedded Target Designer and Component Designer:

On my Windows Embedded image I have two driver components that are "conflicting", but not for IO reasons.

The first driver component is the touchscreen driver that includes its own serial port enumerator called `pmserenum.sys`.

The second driver component, which is for a PCI serial port controller, normally uses Microsoft's default `serenum.sys` serial port enumerator.  However, after FBA, for some reason it's using the touch-screen's `pmserenum.sys` file instead, and the serial ports don't work.

How can I force the serial port driver component to use `serenum.sys` instead of `pmserenum.sys`?  It works perfectly if the touchscreen driver (and therefore `pmserenum.sys`) isn't present.

Screenshots attached:

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/5615/badbehaviour.png - this is how it looks after FBA
http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/4716/goodbehaviour.png - this is how it should look

Comment: This is hardware based question, belongs on serverfault.com!

Comment: Somewhat hardware based...specifically he's asking about drivers. Not sure it belongs on serverfault, since it doesn't appear to have anything to do with servers.

Comment: Yeah it's kindof a grey area - I think it's more of a software development problem given that with Windows Embedded you must design and build your deploy-able image before running it, and this problem is a design-time problem. But I'm happy to put it wherever the people that can help me hang out!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just right-click the device in device manager, choose 'update driver', and then manually specify the correct driver? Instead of letting it autodetect which driver.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to fix this problem at design time - The image should be workable without requiring manual configuration after FBA (First Boot Agent) has run.